# Small strange rendering bug

Tags: javascript, css, rendering, semantic-ui

There are two small "bugs" when I render my CSS tabs. If I press the third tab then the vertical line to the left disappears. In the example in the manual from [semantic-ui](/questions/tagged/semantic-ui) it doesn't happen and the line is there when I press "third". I wonder what can be wrong with the code.

```js
$(function () {
   $('.menu .item').tab();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
  <a class="item active" data-tab="first">First</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="second">Second</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="third">Third</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="first">
  First
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">
  Second
</div>
<div style="margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px" class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="third">
  Third
</div>
```

If you compare pressing "second" to "third" then the vertical line to the left disappears which it should not do. Can you find the error?

Comment: It looks like the left border doesn't really go away, it's just shifting left for some reason and getting hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `.ui.attached.segment` class form semantic.min.css , it has a margin: 0 -1px which adds a margin left and right of -1px.

For the second tab, this margin seems to be overriden by `.ui.tabular.menu+.attached:not(.top).segment+.attached:not(.top).segment` whereas its not overriden for the third one.

A simple fix would be to add a margin-right/left of 0px to the third tab

Comment: It worked! :-) But why does it happen to me and not in the example?